# Asymptotic formula for $\sum_{n\leq x}\mu(n)[x/n]^2$ and the Totient summatory function $\sum_{n\leq x} \phi(n)$

Tags: analysis, number-theory, analytic-number-theory, multiplicative-function

I would like to show (for $x \ge 2$) that $$\sum_{n \le x}\mu(n)\left[\frac{x}{n}\right]^2 = \frac{x^2}{\zeta(2)} + O(x \log(x)).$$

I already have the identity $$\sum_{n \le x}\mu(n)\left[\frac{x}{n}\right] = 1$$ but the method to show this does not extend to my case.

I don't know how to approach this problem so any advice would be very welcome!

---

Since $$\left[\frac{x}{n}\right]^2 = \left(\frac{x}{n}\right)^2 + O(\frac{x}{n})$$ we have $$\sum_{n \le x}\mu(n)\left[\frac{x}{n}\right]^2 = \sum_{n \le x} \mu(n) \left(\frac{x}{n}\right)^2 + O(\sum_{n \le x} \mu(n) \frac{x}{n})$$ and the value estimate is $\frac{1}{\zeta(2)}$ so it remains to show that the error estimate is $O(x \log(x))$.

Comment: Just note that $[x/n]^2 = (x/n)^2 + O(x/n)$, and $\sum_{n \leq x} \mu(n) n^{-2} = \zeta(2)^{-1} + O(1/x)$.

Comment: @sos440, thanks for that idea - that must be it because I get the right terms but I don't know how to get the error estimate to be $x \log(x)$.

Comment: The error term is easily derived, once we observe that $|\mu(n)|  \leq 1$. Then $$\sum_{n\leq x} \mu(n) O(x/n) = O\left( \sum_{n\leq x} x/n \right) = O(x \log x).$$ This is in fact a very crude estimation, so there is a chance for the estimation to be improved, at least as I think.

Comment: @sos440, it is very simple when you do it but seems very complex when I try! Thanks again!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since sos440 provided the answer in the comments, a natural question is how much better can we do?

**Edit:**  Recently, I actually had to do the contour integration and use Perrons formula as I previously suggested.  It turns out that improving the error term is quite a difficult problem, and you **cannot** do much better then $x\log x$.

**Relation to the Sum of Euler's Totient Function:**

We can show that $$\sum_{n\leq x}\mu(n)[x/n]^2=-1+2\sum_{n\leq x}\phi(n)$$ so that analyzing your sum is equivalent to analyzing the totient summatory function.

**The History Of The Error Term For The Totient Sum**

In 1874, Mertens proved the result you wanted above, namely that $$\sum_{n\leq x}\phi(n)=\frac{3}{\pi^{2}}x^{2}+O\left(x\log x\right).$$  Throughout we use the notation $\Phi(x)=\sum_{n\leq x}\phi(n)$ for the summatory function, and $E(x)=\Phi(x)-\frac{3}{\pi^{2}}x^{2}$ for the error function.

The best unconditional result is given by Walfisz 1963: $$E(x)\ll x\left(\log x\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}\left(\log\log x\right)^{\frac{4}{3}}.$$

In 1930, Chowla and Pillai showed this cannot be improved much more, and that $E(x)$ is **not** $$o\left(x\log\log\log x\right).$$

In particular, they showed that $\sum_{n\leq x}E(n)\sim\frac{3}{2\pi^{2}}x^{2}$ so that $E(n)\asymp n$ on average. In 1950, Erdos and Shapiro proved that there exists $c$ such that for infinitely many positive integers $N,M$ we have $$E(N)>cN\log\log\log\log N\ \ \text{and}\ \ E(M)<-cM\log\log\log\log M, $$

or more concisely

$$E(x)=\Omega_{\pm}\left(x\log\log\log\log x\right).$$

In 1987 Montgomery improved this to

$$E(x)=\Omega_{\pm}\left(x\sqrt{\log\log x}\right).$$

**Sum of Relatively Prime Pairs in the Grid:**
Lastly, it is interesting to notice that $$\sum_{d\leq x}\mu(d)\left[\frac{x}{d}\right]^{2}=\sum_{d\leq x}\mu(d)\left(\sum_{s\leq\frac{x}{d}}1\right)\left(\sum_{r\leq\frac{x}{d}}1\right)$$

$$\sum_{d\leq x}\sum_{r,s\leq\frac{x}{d}}\mu(d)=\sum_{m,n\leq x}\sum_{d|\gcd(m,n)}\mu(d)=\sum_{\begin{array}{c}
m,n\leq x\\
\gcd(m,n)=1\end{array}}1$$which is the number of relatively prime pairs of integers both of which are less then $x$.

Hope that helps,

**Added:** At some point, I wrote a [long blog post](http://enaslund.wordpress.com/2012/01/15/the-sum-of-the-totient-function-and-montgomerys-lower-bound/) about this, complete with a proof of Montgomery's lower bound.

Comment: Hey Eric, I am very interested in seeing how to prove the first statement (the relation to $\Phi(x)$).

Comment: @Carolus: Notice that $\sum_{k\leq n}\varphi(n)$  counts the number of relatively prime pairs of integers in the $n\times n$  box which lie on or below the diagonal.  In other words

$$\sum_{k\leq n}\varphi(n)=\sum_{\begin{array}{c}
1\leq k\leq m\leq n\\
(m,k)=1
\end{array}}1\ \text{so that }-1+2\sum_{k\leq n}\varphi(n)=\sum_{\begin{array}{c}
m,k\leq n\\
(m,k)=1
\end{array}}1.$$  The $-1$ comes from counting the point $(1,1)$ twice.  This sum then equals $$\sum_{d\leq n}\mu(d)\left[\frac{n}{d}\right]^{2}$$ by the reasoning in the last paragraph of my answer.

Comment: @Carolus: Here is an alternative proof which is simpler: Since $\phi(n)=\sum_{d|n}\mu(d)\frac{n}{d}$  we see that $$\sum_{k\leq n}\varphi(k)=\sum_{k\leq n}\sum_{d|k}\mu(d)\frac{k}{d}$$ Upon switching the order of summation this becomes $$=\sum_{d\leq n}\mu(d)\sum_{k\leq\frac{n}{d}}k=\sum_{d\leq n}\mu(d)\frac{\left[\frac{n}{d}\right]\left(\left[\frac{n}{d}\right]+1\right)}{2}.$$ As $\sum_{d\leq n}\mu(d)\left[\frac{n}{d}\right]=1,$ we see that $$-1+2\sum_{k\leq n}\varphi(k)=\sum_{d\leq n}\mu(d)\left[\frac{n}{d}\right]^{2}$$ as desired.

Comment: Thank you very much. This helps a lot.

Answer (score 3):

So you have 
\begin{align*}
\sum\limits_{n \leq x} \mu(n)\biggl[\frac{x}{n}\biggr]^{2} &= \sum\limits_{n \leq x} \mu(n)\cdot\biggl(\frac{x}{n}-\biggl\{\frac{x}{n}\biggr\}\biggr)^{2} \\ &= x^{2}\sum\limits_{n \leq x }\frac{\mu(n)}{n^{2}} -2x \cdot\mathcal{O}(\log{x}) + \mathcal{O}(x)
\end{align*}

To find the first sum note that: 
\begin{align*}x^{2} \sum\limits_{n \leq x } \frac{\mu(n)}{n^{2}} &= x^{2}\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(n)}{n^{2}} - x^{2}\sum\limits_{n > x} \frac{\mu(n)}{n^{2}} \\ &= \frac{x^{2}}{\zeta(2)} + \mathcal{O}\biggl(x^{2}\sum\limits_{n >x}\frac{1}{n^{2}}\biggr) \\ &= \frac{x^{2}}{\zeta(2)} + \mathcal{O}\Biggr(x^{2}\Biggl[\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{2}}-\sum\limits_{n \leq x } \frac{1}{n^{2}}\Biggr]\Biggr) \\ &= \frac{x^2}{\zeta(2)} + \mathcal{O}\biggl(\frac{x^{2}}{\zeta(2)} + \sum\limits_{n \leq x} \frac{1}{n^{2}}\biggr)
\end{align*}

and finally note that for $s > 0$ $$\sum\limits_{n \leq x} \frac{1}{n^s} = \frac{x^{1-s}}{1-s} + \zeta(s) + \mathcal{O}(x^{-s})$$