# Mean Value of a Multiplicative Function close to $n$ in Terms of the Zeta Function

Tags: number-theory, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, multiplicative-function

Let $f(n)$ be a multiplicative function defined by $f(p^a)=p^{a-1}(p+1)$, where $p$ is a prime number.  How could I obtain a formula for $$\sum_{n\leq x} f(n)$$ with error term $O(x\log{x})$ and express the main term constant in terms of values of Riemann zeta function?

Comment: What constant did you have in mind?

Comment: This is actually not a homework problem. I am preparing my comprehensive exam for analytic number theory. This is one of the problems from past exams.

Comment: This function appears in [Exercise 11 in Chapter 3](https://books.google.com/books?id=3yoBCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA71) in Apostol's book. [The last part](https://books.google.com/books?id=3yoBCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA72) of this exercise is the asymptotic formula
$\sum_{n\le x} \varphi_1(n)=\frac{\zeta(2)}{2\zeta(4)}x^2+O(x\log x)$. (Apostol denotes the function by $\varphi_1$.)

Comment: There was a recent question on MathOverflow about this: [Does this multiplicative function have a name? If so, what is known about it?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/313146#313150)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The following is a more general presentation of a recurring idea which comes up when trying to find the mean value of certain multiplicative functions.  Notice that the exact same steps would give us the result if $f(n)$ was replace by say $\phi(n)$, we would need only modify the calculation for $g(n)$ at the end.

**Heuristics:** Notice $f(n)\approx n$ so that $\frac{f(n)}{n}\approx 1$.  For functions close to one, convolution with the Möbius function will be close to zero, so we can deal with it easily.  Lets define $g(n)=(\mu*\frac{f(d)}{d})(n)=\sum_{d|n}\frac{f(d)}{d}\mu\left(\frac{n}{d}\right)$ so that $(1*g)(n)=\frac{f(n)}{n}$.  The idea will be to rewrite everything in terms of $g$ since $g(n)$ will be small.

**The main sum:** We can write $$\sum_{n\leq x}f(n)=\sum_{n\leq x}n\frac{f(n)}{n}=\sum_{n\leq x}n\sum_{d|n}g(d)=\sum_{d\leq x}g(d)\sum_{n\leq x,\ d|n} n$$  $$=\sum_{d\leq x}dg(d)\sum_{n\leq \frac{x}{d}} n=\sum_{d\leq x}dg(d)\frac{\left[\frac{x}{d}\right]^2+\left[\frac{x}{d}\right]}{2}$$ $$=\frac{x^2}{2}\sum_{d\leq x}\frac{g(d)}{d}+O\left(x\sum_{d\leq x}|g(d)|\right).\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)$$ The error term comes from using $\left[\frac{x}{d}\right]=\frac{x}{d}+O(1)$, and the fact that $$O\left(\sum_{d\leq x}d|g(d)|\left[\frac{x}{d}\right]\right)=+O\left(x\sum_{d\leq x}|g(d)|\right).$$ Thus we see that $$\sum_{n\leq x} f(n)=\frac{x^2}{2}\sum_{d=1}^\infty\frac{g(d)}{d}+O\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\sum_{d>x}\frac{|g(d)|}{d}+x\sum_{d\leq x}|g(d)|\right).$$ Now, using Rankin's trick let $1>\sigma>0$. Then in the first sum $\frac{x}{d}<\frac{x^\sigma}{d^\sigma}$, and in the second sum $1<\frac{x^\sigma}{d^\sigma}$, and so we obtain our final equation that holds for any $0<\sigma<1$:

$$\sum_{n\leq x}f(n)=\frac{x^2}{2}\sum_{d=1}^\infty\frac{g(d)}{d}+O\left(x^{1+\sigma}\sum_{d=1}^\infty \frac{|g(d)|}{d^\sigma}\right),$$ and we choose $\sigma$ to optimize the error term. (For example, for $f(n)=\phi(n)$, we take $\sigma=\frac{1}{\log x}$.)

**Calculating $g(d)$:** Notice that $\frac{f(p^a)}{p^a}=\left(1+\frac{1}{p}\right)$.  Then since $g(p^a)=\frac{f(p^a)}{p^a}-\frac{f(p^{a-1})}{p^{a-1}}$ for $a\geq 2$, we see that $g(p^a)=0$ when $a\geq  2$.  When $a=1$ $g(p)=\frac{f(p)}{p}-1=\frac{1}{p}$.  Hence $$g(n)=\frac{\mu(n)^2}{n}.$$

**Putting this together:**
Letting $\sigma=\frac{1}{\log x}$ we have by $(1)$ that $$\sum_{n\leq x}f(n)=\frac{x^2}{2} \sum_{d=1}^\infty \frac{\mu(d)^2}{d^2}+O(x\log x).$$

Using Euler products, $$\sum_{d=1}^\infty \frac{\mu(d)^2}{d^2}=\prod_p \left(1+\frac{1}{p^2}\right)=\prod_p \left(1-\frac{1}{p^4}\right)\prod_p \left(1-\frac{1}{p^2}\right)^{-1}=\frac{\zeta(2)}{\zeta(4)}.$$  Thus  $$\sum_{n\leq x}f(n)=x^2 \frac{\zeta(2)}{\zeta(4)}+O(x\log x)=\frac{15}{2\pi^2}x^2+O(x\log x).$$

**See also this list of relevant questions:**

- [Multiplicative functions close to $1$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84708/prove-sum-limits-n-leq-x-fracn-phin-ox/84721#84721)
- [Calculating the average of $\text{rad}(n).$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1395269/average-order-of-mathrmradn/1396549#1396549)
- [A complicated sum involving four convolutions of the mobius function.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/371195/to-estimate-sum-m-1n-bigd-bigm2-big-big2/382546#382546)
- [The error term that arises when summing the Totient function.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37863/asymptotic-formula-for-sum-n-leq-x-munx-n2-and-the-totient-summatory-f/38142#38142)
- [Averages of certain arithmetic functions.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/154788/dirichlet-series-and-average-values-of-certain-arithmetic-functions/154808#154808)
- [The average of the $N^{th}$-powerfree part of $n$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1336712/what-is-known-about-these-arithmetical-functions/1489098#1489098)