# Conjecture: $\lim_{N \to +\infty}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^{N}\frac{\phi(k)}{k}=\frac{6}{\pi^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

I was playing around with the series $f(N)=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^{N}\frac{\phi(k)}{k}$ and I found with Wolfram that $f(10,000)=0.607938$, which I noticed was very close to $\frac{6}{\pi^2}$.

I am led to make the following

> **Conjecture:** $\lim_{N \to +\infty}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^{N}\frac{\phi(k)}{k}=\frac{6}{\pi^2}$

Well, is it true?

Note that its obvious that the sum is bounded above by $1$ (since $\phi(k)/k<1$), so it definitely doesn't diverge to infinity. Its also almost always decreasing. So it most likely converges.

Comment: Yes. See the answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/154788/dirichlet-series-and-average-values-of-certain-arithmetic-functions

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/231073/the-constant-in-the-asymptotics-of-sum-1-le-k-le-n-frac-varphikk2?rq=1

Comment: Note that your title and your body ask different questions. Your title does not include the $\frac{1}{N}$.

Comment: yes a typo. fixed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key formula is $$\frac{\phi(n)}{n}=\sum_{d\mid n} \frac{\mu(d)}{d}$$

From this, you get that:

$$\begin{align}f(N)=&\sum_{k=1}^{N}\frac{\phi(k)}{k}\\&=\sum_{k=1}^{N}\sum_{d\mid k} \frac{\mu(d)}{d}\\
&= \sum_{d=1}^{N}\frac{\mu(d)}{d}\left\lfloor\frac N d\right\rfloor\end{align}$$

Then $\left|\left\lfloor\frac N d\right\rfloor - \frac{N}d\right|<1$ so $$\left|\frac{f(N)}N-\sum_{d=1}^{N}\frac{\mu(d)}{d^2}\right|<\frac{1}{N}\sum_{d=1}^{N}\frac1{d^2}< \frac{\zeta(2)}{N}$$

But we know that $$\sum_{d=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(d)}{d^2}=\frac{1}{\zeta(2)}=\frac{6}{\pi^2}$$

Comment: really the OP needs all the details

Comment: There is no further detail needed, except perhaps an explicit appeal to the theorem that if $|a_N-b_N|\to 0$ and $b_N\to C$ then $a_N\to C$. @user1952009

Answer (score 0):

Here's a start:

It is well known that (a,b) = 1 for random a,b with probability $6/\pi^2.$ Then $\phi(k) \sim k \cdot \frac{6}{\pi^2}$ for large k, and because the density of primes is zero, by the definition of $\phi(x),$ so $$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{n\geq k\geq 1}\frac{\phi(k)}{k}\sim \frac{1}{n}\sum_{n\geq k\geq 1} \frac{6}{\pi^2}=\frac{6}{\pi^2}.$$ However this is not very rigorous.

Comment: Yes but it is from this result that you know the density of $(a,b)=1$ is $6/\pi^2$

Comment: @user1952009 : is it not from the Euler product formula and zeta(2)?

Comment: Of course, it is only sort-of true that $\phi(k)/k\to \frac{6}{\pi^2}$. It is not actually true - for example, when $p_i$ are the primes, $\frac{\phi(p_i)}{p_i}\to 1$. Also $\phi(2^n)/2^n = \frac{1}{2}$ for all $n$. So it's just an idea, really