# To estimate $\sum_{m=1}^n \Big(d\big(m^2\big)\Big)^2$

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, multiplicative-function

How may we estimate $$\sum_{m=1}^n \Big(d\big(m^2\big)\Big)^2$$ where for every positive integer $m$ , $d(m)$ denotes the number of positive divisors of $m$  ?

Comment: Are you looking for an asymptotic formula precise upper/lower bounds, or just an order of magnitude?

Comment: @ErickWong: Either an asymptotic formula , or to write the sum as $f(n) + O(g(n))$ , where $f$ and $g$ are some known functions.

Comment: Did you try Perron's formula?

Comment: @Sanchez: To effectively apply Perron's formula I would need a simple looking form of the generating function of $(d(n^2))^2$ , but I cann't recall anything like that.

Comment: @SouvikDey, It's definitely multiplicative. Write the generating L function as a product of some zeta function and something with analtyic continuation pass the pole at 1. This allows you to get the main term by moving the contour pass 1.

Answer (score 4):

In what follows, we calculate the answer for the similar function $f(n)=d\left(n\right)^{2}$.  These methods can be extended to $d(n^2)^2$ without much change.  I originally misread the question, and as a result, did the calculation for $d(n)^2$.

On prime powers, $f(p^{k})=(k+1)^{2},$ and most importantly, $f(p)=4$, and $f(p^k)$ is not too large. Let $$g(n)=\left(f*\mu*\mu*\mu*\mu\right)(n).$$  Then $g(p)=O\left(\frac{1}{p}\right),$ and so $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{|g(n)|}{n}=\prod_{p}\left(1+\frac{|g(p)|}{p}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^{2}}\right)\right)<\infty.$$ Now, since $g*1*1*1*1(n)=f(n),$ it follows that $$\sum_{n\leq x}f(n)=\sum_{abcde\leq x}g(a)=\sum_{a\leq x}g(a)\sum_{bcde\leq\frac{x}{a}}1.$$ Since $$\sum_{bcde\leq\frac{x}{a}}1=\sum_{n\leq\frac{x}{a}}d_{4}(n)=\frac{x}{a}\log^{3}\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)+O\left(\frac{x}{a}\log^{2}\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)\right),$$ we have that $$\sum_{n\leq x}f(n)=x\sum_{a\leq x}\frac{g(a)}{a}\log^{3}\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)+O\left(x\log^{2}(x)\sum_{a\leq x}\frac{|g(a)|}{a}\right),$$ and so  $$\sum_{n\leq x}f(n)\sim cx\log^{3}(x)$$ for some constant $c>0$.  consider the Dirichlet series $$F(s)=\prod_p\left(1+\frac{f(p)}{p^s}+\frac{f(p^2)}{p^{2s}}+\cdots\right).$$  Then $$\frac{F(s)}{\zeta(s)^4}=\prod_p\left(1+\frac{4}{p^s}+\frac{9}{p^{2s}}+\frac{16}{p^{3s}}+\cdots\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{p^s}\right)^4.$$  We consider $\zeta(s)^4$ since the coefficient of $p^s$ is $4$.  Letting $x=\frac{1}{p^s}$, we are trying to find a nice form for $$g(x)=(1-x)^4\sum_{k=0}^\infty (k+1)^2 x^k.$$  Using generating series, we have that $$g(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\left(x\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x^{k+1}\right)=\frac{d}{dx}\left(x\frac{d}{dx}\frac{x}{1-x}\right)=\frac{x+1}{\left(1-x\right)^{3}}.$$ Hence $g(x)=1-x^{2},$ and so $$F(s)=\zeta(s)^{4}\prod_{p}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^{2s}}\right)=\frac{\zeta(s)^{4}}{\zeta(2s)}.$$

Comment: $f(p^k)=(2k+1)^2$ not $(k+1)^2$ , right ?

Comment: @SouvikDey yes it should be $(2k+1)^2$

Comment: @Ethan: Yup , so you noted it too?