# What is the limiting mean value of the product of the exponents in the prime factorization of numbers?

Tags: limits, number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility, analytic-number-theory

Let $n = p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}\cdots p_m^{a_m}$ be the prime factorization of $n$ and let $f(n) = a_1 a_2 \cdots a_m$. Using a heuristic argument I am able to show that the mean value of $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k = 1}^n f(k)$ is close to

$$
\bigg(2 - \frac{1}{\zeta(2)}\bigg)\bigg(N_c + \frac{1}{\zeta(2)} - \frac{2}{\zeta(3)}\bigg) - \frac{1}{\zeta(2)} + \frac{2}{\zeta(3)} \approx 1.95979
$$

where $N_c \approx 1.7052$ is the [Niven's constant](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/NivensConstant.html). Experimental data seems to be consistent with this heuristics. For $n = 10^6$, the mean is $1.9406$ while for $n = 1.42 \times 10^{10}$, the mean increased slightly to $1.94357$.

**Question**: What is the limiting value of the mean? Is there a closed form for the mean of $f(n)$?

Comment: What do you mean by a closed form of $f(n)$? The form in which you define it is already quite simple; what sort of other form are you looking for? Also, why are those two questions combined in Question $1$? They don't seem to be related. Perhaps you meant to ask about a closed form of the mean of $f(n)$?

Comment: @joriki Yes meant the closed form for the mean of $f(n)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $h$ be a [multiplicative function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_function) defined by $h(p^k)=k$ for all prime powers $p^k$. Then you are trying to calculate  the mean value of $h$, and we have that:

> **Theorem:** $$\sum_{n\leq x} h(n)=x\frac{\zeta(3)\zeta(2)}{\zeta(6)} + O\left(\sqrt{x}\right),$$ where $\zeta$ is the [Riemann zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function) and
> where the error term uses [Big-O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), meaning it is at most $C\sqrt{x}$ for some constant $C>0$.

This can be done using the general method in this answer:
[On the mean value of a multiplicative function: Prove that $\sum\limits_{n\leq x} \frac{n}{\phi(n)} =O(x) $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84708/on-the-mean-value-of-a-multiplicative-function-prove-that-sum-limits-n-leq-x/84721#84721)

The idea is that since $h$ is "very close" to $1$, $f=\mu*h$ will be very close to zero, where $\mu$ is the [Mobius mu function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function), and $*$ represents [Dirichlet convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_convolution). In particular, computing the Mobius inversion, we have $f(p)=0$, $f(p^k)=1$ for $k\geq 2$, and $(1*f)=h$.

From the method in the above answer, we have

> $$\sum_{n\leq x} h(n)=\sum_{n\leq x} (1*f)(n)=\sum_{n\leq x}\sum_{d|n}f(d)=\sum_{d\leq x} f(d)\left[\frac{x}{d}\right]$$ and using $[z]=z+O(1)$ this is $$=x\sum_{d\leq x} \frac{f(d)}{d}+O\left(\sum_{d\leq x} |f(d)|\right).$$

Thus it follows that

$$\sum_{n\leq x} h(n) = x\sum_{d}\frac{f(d)}{d}+O(\sqrt{x}),$$
and hence the mean value is $$\sum_{d}\frac{f(d)}{d} = \prod_{p}\left(1+\frac{1}{p(p-1)}\right)$$

where the final form is an [Euler-product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_product). The Euler product can be rearranged as
$$\prod_{p}\left(1+\frac{1}{p(p-1)}\right)=\prod_{p}\left(\frac{p^{2}-p+1}{p(p-1)}\right)$$
$$=\prod_{p}\left(\frac{p^{2}-p+1}{p(p-1)}\right)=\prod_{p}\left(\frac{p^{6}-1}{p(p^{2}-1)(p^{3}-1)}\right)=\frac{\zeta(3)\zeta(2)}{\zeta(6)}.$$

---

**See also this list of similar questions using the same technique:**

- [Mean Value of a Multiplicative Function close to $1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84708/on-the-mean-value-of-a-multiplicative-function-prove-that-sum-limits-n-leq-x/84721#84721) (linked above already)
- [Mean Value of a Multiplicative Function close to $n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90120/mean-value-of-a-multiplicative-function-close-to-n-in-terms-of-the-zeta-functi/90125#90125)
- [Calculating the average of $\text{rad}(n).$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1395269/average-order-of-mathrmradn/1396549#1396549)
- [A complicated sum involving four convolutions of the mobius function.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/371195/to-estimate-sum-m-1n-bigd-bigm2-big-big2/382546#382546)
- [The error term that arises when summing the Totient function.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37863/asymptotic-formula-for-sum-n-leq-x-munx-n2-and-the-totient-summatory-f/38142#38142)
- [Averages of certain arithmetic functions.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/154788/dirichlet-series-and-average-values-of-certain-arithmetic-functions/154808#154808)
- [The average of the $N^{th}$-powerfree part of $n$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1336712/what-is-known-about-these-arithmetical-functions/1489098#1489098)

Answer (score 1):

I think the limit would be (1 + 1/p^2 + 1/p^3 …) multiplied over all primes. The sum is 1+1/p(p-1), and this needs multiplying over all primes. (1+1/2)(1+1/6)(1+1/20)(1+1/42)…

This seems rather close to your result.

Comment: Can you please add how you deduced that?

Comment: $\prod_p \big(1 + \frac{1}{p(p-1)}\big) = \frac{\zeta(2)\zeta(3)}{\zeta(6)} \approx 1.943596$ is the Landau Totient constant https://mathoverflow.net/questions/368424/a-number-similar-to-landaus-totient-constant