# What is known about these arithmetical functions?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, terminology, analytic-number-theory, multiplicative-function

Let $n=\prod_p p^{c_p}$, $N\in \mathbb N$ and 
$$
\alpha_N(n)=\prod_p p^{c_p \bmod N}.
$$
The function $\alpha_N$ is multiplicative since $\alpha_N(n)\alpha_N(m)=\alpha_N(nm)$ for co-prime $n$ and $m$ and completely multiplicative for a subset of $\mathbb N$.

Further let
 $$\log \alpha_N(n)=
A_N(n)=\sum_p (c_p \bmod N) \log p.
$$
 It also reminds me to a sum of an adapted kind of [von Mangoldt function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Mangoldt_function), with following definition:
$$
    \Lambda^\star(n) = \begin{cases} \log p & \text{if }n=p^c \text{ for some prime } p \text{ and integer } c \ge 1 \text{ and } c\bmod N =1, \\ 0 & \text{otherwise.} \end{cases} 
$$

PS: Since the taste of the question was changed, some of the comments might be misleading. Sorry for that...

Comment: I don't think this sort of functions should have or deserve a name.  There are pretty weird functions such as the constant function $\alpha_1\equiv 1$, the function $\alpha_2$ where $\alpha_2(1)=1$ and, for an integer $n>1$, $\alpha_2(n)$ is the largest prime divisor of $n$, and the function $\alpha_3$ where $\alpha_3(n)=1$ if $n$ is odd, and $\alpha_3(n)=2$ if $n$ is even.

Comment: @Batominovski the function $\alpha_3(n)$ has a name! It's called modulus: $\alpha_3(n)=n \bmod 2$...and I also don't see why your other example should be so weird...

Comment: I know that $\alpha_3$ is actually reduction modulo $2$.  The point is these functions don't really seem to have any coherent properties.  Individually, these functions themselves are not very weird, but, collectively, the assumption that there should be a named property which includes them all is what sounds utterly weird.

Comment: @Batominovski but after all it's a set, as you say. And the set of weird functions (you named it) has already three members...

Comment: Believe me that there are infinitely many such "weird functions."  One family can be described as follows.  Let $p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_k$ be a collection of pairwise distinct positive prime numbers and let $d$ be a positive integer divided by none of the $p_i$'s.  Take $\alpha(n)$ to be the product $d$ and all primes $p_i$'s such that $p_i$ divides $n$ (obviously, $\alpha(1)=d$ in this case).  Now, tell me: why should we give the functions that satisfy your functional equation any proper names?  They don't seem to have any interesting values.

Comment: @Batominovski in fact I completely changed it. Maybe parts of our discussion doesn't make sense to some reader. Sorry for that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would call this function the *$N^{th}$-power free part* of $n$, which generalizes the $N=2$ case of the squarefree part of an integer.

Specifically, we have that $$\alpha_N(n)=n\prod_{p^{kN}|n}\left(\frac{1}{p^{N}}\right),$$

and $\alpha_N(n)$ removes all of the $N^{th}$ powers that divide $n$ leaving behind the $N^{th}$-power free part. It will share many properties with the squarefree part. For example, $\alpha_N(n)=n$ for any $N^{th}$-power free integer, which is a set of density $\frac{1}{\zeta(N)}$ in the integers. The average of $\alpha_N(n)$ can be computing using the techniques in the answer [Mean Value of a Multiplicative Function close to $n$ in Terms of the Zeta Function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90120/mean-value-of-a-multiplicative-function-close-to-n-in-terms-of-the-zeta-functi/90125#90125). Since $$\mu*\frac{\alpha_{N}(n)}{n}=\begin{cases}
1 & k=0\\
0 & k\neq0\ \text{mod}\ N\\
-\frac{p^{N}-1}{p^{aN}} & k=aN
\end{cases}
 $$ and we find that $$\sum_{n\leq x}\alpha_N(n)=\frac{x^2}{2}\frac{\zeta(2N)}{\zeta(N)}+O(x\log x).$$ (The error term is $O(x)$ for all $N\geq 3$.) In particular, when $N=2$, we find that the squarefree part of $n$ has average $$\sum_{n\leq x}\alpha_2(n)=\sum_{n\leq x} \text{squarefree}(n)=\frac{x^2\pi^2}{30}+O(x\log x).$$ Similarly, the fourth-powerfree part of $n$ has average $$\sum_{n\leq x}\alpha_4(n)=\sum_{n\leq x}\text{fourth-powerfree-part}(n)=\frac{\pi^4x^2}{210}+O(x).$$