# Finding $\lim_{n\to\infty}\Phi(n)/n^2$, When $\Phi(n)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\phi(n)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This exercise is meant to be 'explored' computationally. However, I implemented it in C++ and did not get anything better than a sequence of pseudo-random numbers.

> Let $\Phi(n)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\phi(n)$. Investigate the value of $\Phi(n)/n^2$ for increasingly large values of $n$, such as $n=100$, $n=1000$, and $n=10000$. Can you make a conjecture about the limit of this ratio as $n$ grows large without bound?

Notice that $\Phi(n)=n\phi(n)$. Hence, $\Phi(n)/n^2=\phi(n)/n$. Moreover, the largest value $\phi(n)/n$ ever attains is $1$ at $n=1$; everything else falls within the interval $(0,1)$, and the closest it gets to $1$ again is when $n$ is prime (since $\phi(p)=p-1$, and $(p-1)/p\approx1$ for very large primes $p$).

However, I am tempted to say that this function diverges, and that no conjecture about its limit can be concluded as a result.

What do you guys think?

Comment: Since $\phi(n)$ is asymptotically $n$, I'm tempted to say $\Phi(n)/n^2$ approaches $1/2$, as $\sum\limits_{i=1}^ni=\frac{i^2+i}{2}$.

Comment: I think the question is supposed to be about $\sum_{i=1}^n\phi(i)$.

Comment: Gerry, I thought the same. However, I copied the book's question character by character (*Elementary Number Theory and Its Applications* 5E. by Kenneth H. Rosen, page 237). Could he have made a typo?

Comment: I think the function $f(n) = \phi(n)/n$ has no limit, because for any value taken by $f$, say $f(n_0)$, then $(n_0^k)_{k>0}$ defines a subsequence that converges to this value (using the fact that $f(n_0^k) = f(n_0)$).

Comment: Hey guys, look at what I found.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#Growth_of_the_function

Is that corroborating that the limit indeed does not exist? The mathematics are too convoluted for me to understand at this point. :/

Comment: Where do you get $\Phi(n) = n \phi(n)$ from ?

Comment: $\Phi(n)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\phi(n)=\phi(n)+\phi(n)+\cdots+\phi(n)=n\phi(n)$.

Comment: From the fact that $\phi(1)+\cdots+\phi(n)=3n^2/\pi^2+O(n\log n)$, assuming the author meant $\phi(i)$ we have that the limits is $3/\pi^2$. Note: this is near the bottom of the wikipedia page.

Comment: @Josue Molina: I checked my copy of the Rosen book, fifth edition. Undoubtedly there is a typo in the book.

Comment: @JoelCohen: you are correct that $\phi(n)/n$ does not tend to a limit, but your argument is incomplete - you need to note that $f$ is not a constant sequence.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a very old result that says
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n \varphi(k)}{n^2}=\frac{3}{\pi^2}.$$

The error term I have in notes is $O(x(\log x)^{2/3}(\log\log x)^{4/3})$, but undoubtedly there have been improvements on that.  There is a large literature.

**Added:** The OP quoted correctly the textbook source of the problem, which asks about the behaviour of $(\sum_{i=1}^n\varphi(n))/n^2$.  This is undoubtedly a typo, since $\sum_{i=1}^n\varphi(n)=n\varphi(n)$.

The ratio $\dfrac{\varphi(n)}{n}$ certainly bounces around a lot, and can be made arbitrarily close to $0$, and, much more easily, arbitrarily close to $1$.

Comment: Is that considering $\Phi(n)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\phi(n)$ or $\Phi(n)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\phi(i)$?

Comment: What you wrote, both in the post and in the comment, cannot be right, since you are writing $\sum_{i=1}^n \varphi(n)$.  I assumed that you mean $\sum_{i=1}^n\varphi(i)$.  If we are summing over the divisors of $n$, that is an entirely different function, easy to get explicit formulas for, but somewhat chaotic.

Comment: The typo is fixed in the sixth edition, which defines $\Phi(n)$ to be $\sum_{i=1}^n \phi(i)$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: "Undoubtedly there have been improvements on that."   Surprisingly, there haven't been any.  That result is due to Walfisz, and it remains the best.  See this blog post for details: http://enaslund.wordpress.com/2012/01/15/the-sum-of-the-totient-function-and-montgomerys-lower-bound/

Answer (score 4):

[Here is a detailed note](http://enaslund.wordpress.com/2012/01/15/the-sum-of-the-totient-function-and-montgomerys-lower-bound/) regarding the Totient Summatory function.  Part 1 and 2 should be of interest, and in part 2 there is a short proof.

Also see this Math Stack Exchange [question and answer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37863/asymptotic-formula-for-munx-n2-summation/38142#38142)

Answer (score 1):

i found an interesting connection between the following probability problem and your question:

**Question**: If 2 integers are randomly chosen between 1 and n, then as n tends to infinity, find the probability that the chosen numbers are coprime.

Now the probability that 2 numbers are not divisible by a prime p is $(1-1/p^2)$. So we require the infinite product:

$$ \prod_{p}{(1-\frac{1}{p^2})}$$

And this can be easily seen to be $\frac{1}{\zeta(2)}= \frac{6}{\pi^2}$ which is the answer, where $ \zeta(z) $is the Reimann zeta function.

Thinking in terms of definition, probability is ratio of favourable outcomes and total outcomes.
Now, number of possible pairs of numbers is $ n²$.

What is the number of coprime pairs $(x,y)$,$ 1≤x≤y≤n$, x,y being integers?
Setting $y=k$, the possible pairs is $\phi(k)$, because $ \phi(k) $is the number of integers less than k and prime to k.

So, required answer is just:

$$ \lim_{n\to \infty}  \frac{2(\phi(1)+\phi(2)+...\phi(n))}{n^2}$$

(2 introduced so that  if $(x,y) $are coprime, then and$ (y,x)$ is also coprime.)

So the twice the limit in your question is the probability that 2 chosen numbers in 1 to n is coprime!

So your answer must be
$$ \lim_{n\to \infty}  \frac{(\phi(1)+\phi(2)+...\phi(n))}{n^2} =\frac{1}{2\zeta(2)}= \frac{3}{\pi^2}$$