# Ratio of sum of Euler's totient to $n$: $\lim_{n \to \infty} {\log \left( \sum_{k=2}^n \varphi(k) \right) \over \log(n)}$

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, totient-function

This is more a casual/recreational question...

It seems to me, that the limit as given in the subject line
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}  {\log \left( \sum_{k=2}^n \varphi(k) \right) \over \log(n)} = \log_n \left( \sum_{k=2}^n \varphi(k) \right)  \le 2 $$

Possibly this is somehow trivial. And does it approach *2* in the limit?

Comment: Hint: $\sum_{k=1}^n \varphi(k) \leq \sum_{k=1}^n k \leq \sum_{k=1}^n n = n^2$

Comment: @Peter: ...arrrggh...I'm stupid! True; that's correct. I'd thought already myself about your left inequality, but didn't arrive at the second. But is there a certain limit for that formula? Or a better expression?

Comment: Strictly speaking, the second inequality is unnecessary; the sum can be evaluated explicitly as $n(n+1)/2$; which behaves just like $n^2$ when taking logarithms.

Comment: @Peter: well, what I'm just thinking about was whether there is some modification of the Euler-product to arrive at the limit as n goes to infinity. But I'm not sure about this...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Asymptotic formula for $\mu(n)[x/n]^2$ summation](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37863/asymptotic-formula-for-munx-n2-summation)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Thm**: *We have*
$$
\sum_{n < x} \varphi(n) \sim \frac{3}{\pi^2} x^2
$$
**Proof:**
Since
$$
n = \sum_{d | n} \varphi(d)
$$
by Moebius inversion we get
$$
\varphi(n) = n \sum_{d | n} \frac{\mu(d)}{d}
$$
Therefore
$$
\sum_{n < x} \varphi(n) = \sum_{n < x} n \sum_{d | n} \frac{\mu(d)}{d}
$$
Interchanging summation we get
$$
\sum_{d < x} \frac{\mu(d)}{d} \sum_{d | n, n < x} n
$$
The inner sum equals
$$
d \cdot \frac{x^2}{2 d^2} + O(x) = \frac{x^2}{2d} + O(x)
$$
Therefore the final answer is
$$
\sum_{d < x} \frac{\mu(d)}{2 d^2} \cdot x^2 + O(x\log x) = 
\frac{1}{2\zeta(2)} x^2 + O(x\log x)
$$
because the later sum converges to $1 / \zeta(2) = 6/\pi^2$. 
$\square$

EDIT: In particular your limit is indeed equal to $2$!

EDIT 2: Actually for most integers $\varphi(n) \asymp n$.

In fact the proportion of integers $n <  x$ such that $\alpha n < \varphi(n) < \beta n$, with $\alpha < 1$ converges to a continuous distribution function $$\mathbb{P}(\alpha < X < \beta) > 0$$ where explicitely $$ X := \prod_{p} \bigg ( 1 - \frac{X(p)}{p} \bigg )$$ and the $X(p)$ are independent random variables with $$\mathbb{P}(X(p) = 1) = \frac{1}{p} \text{ and } \mathbb{P}(X(p) = 0) = 1 - \frac{1}{p}.$$ 
This is **Schoenberg's theorem**.

Comment: Very nice! Numerically it comes out very near for *x* up to $2^{19}$ . I'll have to chew on this a bit more, thanks for the hint to the Moebius-inversion!

Comment: Hi! I've added an edit on Schoenberg's theorem which might interest you. If you have any questions about the proof of either let me know!

Comment: Thanks again. I accepted it also now, because it was initially most hepful and also because the question seems to get closed soon.

Answer (score 4):

We have the asymptotic result $$\sum_{n\leq x}\phi(n)=\frac{3}{\pi^{2}}x^{2}+O\left(x\log x\right),$$ so your limit is $2$.

For a complete overview with proof of the above as well as proofs of the $\Omega$ type results for the error term, take a look at this [Blog Post.](http://enaslund.wordpress.com/2012/01/15/the-sum-of-the-totient-function-and-montgomerys-lower-bound/)

A solution to this question can also be found in two other answers of mine on Math Stack Exchange:  [Probability that two random numbers are coprime](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64498/probability-that-two-random-numbers-are-coprime/64499#64499) and [Asymptotic formula for $\sum_{n\leq x}\mu(n)[x/n]^2$ and the Totient summatory function $\sum_{n\leq x} \phi(n)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37863/asymptotic-formula-for-munx-n2-summation/38142#38142)

Comment: Thanks for the link. Your answer there is much interesting!